# How to get the text count from String

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have below string

```
   Salary and Benefits <span class="read-barfull"></span><span class="read-barfull"></span><span class="read-barfull"></span><span class="read-barfull"></span><span class="read-barfull"></span>
Job Security <span class="read-barfull"></span><span class="read-barfull"></span><span class="read-barfull"></span><span class="read-barfull"></span><span class="read-barfull"></span>
Career Growth <span class="read-barfull"></span><span class="read-barfull"></span><span class="read-barfull"></span><span class="read-barfull"></span><span class="read-barnone"></span>
Work Environment <span class="read-barfull"></span><span class="read-barfull"></span><span class="read-barfull"></span><span class="read-barfull"></span><span class="read-barfull"></span>
CEO Rating <span class="read-barfull"></span><span class="read-barfull"></span><span class="read-barfull"></span><span class="read-barfull"></span><span class="read-barfull"></span>
```

i need to display the count like below format(no of "read-barfull" count)

```
Salary and Benefits 5
Job Security 5
Career Growth 4
Work Environment 5
CEO Rating 5
```

please help me to get the format 
thank you in advance

Comment: Sure, count the `<span class="read-barfull"></span>` per line. What have you tried yet?

Comment: my question is every span class before some text is there ..how can i get the span class name by using its text?

Comment: trim the string and count the occurrences of <span class="read-barfull"></span> will suffice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the "token" string you want to count is static (or at least "predefined") you can do something like the following, which uses Apache commons-lang:

```
String str = "Salary and Benefits <span class=\"read-barfull\"></span><span class=\"read-barfull\"></span><span class=\"read-barfull\"></span><span class=\"read-barfull\"></span><span class=\"read-barfull\"></span>";
String spanText = "<span class=\"read-barfull\"></span>";
int count = StringUtils.countMatches(str, spanText);
```

Comment: what is the package name for Stringutils

Comment: By the way, you can probably do the same using regular expression, but it would probably look rather "nasty" and I would avoid it in this case.

Comment: My pleasure - and when you get the chance - please mark this as "answered".

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it with Jsoup (since your question was tagged with it). General idea is to

- read HTML line by line,
- get text represented by this line of HTML
- select all `<span class="read-barfull"></span>` elements (regardless if they are empty or not, but you can change it if you want) - simple `select("span.read-barfull")` will do this for us
- print count of selected `span` elements (`size()` is useful here)

Code:

```
String html = "Salary and Benefits <span class=\"read-barfull\"></span><span class=\"read-barfull\"></span><span class=\"read-barfull\"></span><span class=\"read-barfull\"></span><span class=\"read-barfull\"></span>\r\n" + 
        "Job Security <span class=\"read-barfull\"></span><span class=\"read-barfull\"></span><span class=\"read-barfull\"></span><span class=\"read-barfull\"></span><span class=\"read-barfull\"></span>\r\n" + 
        "Career Growth <span class=\"read-barfull\"></span><span class=\"read-barfull\"></span><span class=\"read-barfull\"></span><span class=\"read-barfull\"></span><span class=\"read-barnone\"></span>\r\n" + 
        "Work Environment <span class=\"read-barfull\"></span><span class=\"read-barfull\"></span><span class=\"read-barfull\"></span><span class=\"read-barfull\"></span><span class=\"read-barfull\"></span>\r\n" + 
        "CEO Rating <span class=\"read-barfull\"></span><span class=\"read-barfull\"></span><span class=\"read-barfull\"></span><span class=\"read-barfull\"></span><span class=\"read-barfull\"></span>";

Scanner sc = new Scanner(html);
while(sc.hasNextLine()){
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(sc.nextLine());
    System.out.println(doc.text()+" "+doc.select("span.read-barfull").size());
}
```

Output:

```
Salary and Benefits 5
Job Security 5
Career Growth 4
Work Environment 5
CEO Rating 5
```

Comment: its awsome @pshemo .
it reduces a the lot of work for me
Tq TQ very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Separate your logic into two ways

1. create a `List<String>`
2. Iterate List & search the word using String Buffer or Split and get counter increments. {do simple logic to separate "read-barfull" and string "key"(ie.Salary and Benefits)
3. Get count value from that.
4. create a `Map<String,Integer>`
   that`s all.